# Jquery Calorie Calculator can't add more than 1 variable

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement, boolean, conditional-statements

I'm trying to build a calorie calculator which takes attributes like:

Vegan
Vegetarian
Ketogen
etc.

I managed to get the macronutrients work, but I'm struggling with adding more than 1 conditional to the equation. 'vegan' works fine, but using the same code for another attribute 'vegetarian' yields no result. I'm pretty sure its a logic error somewhere but I can't figure it out.

Here's my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.ingredient').click(function () {
        var totalNum = $('#total');
        var totalCarbs = $('#totalCarbs');
        var totalFats = $('#totalFats');
        var totalProteins = $('#totalProteins');
        var pressed = $(this).hasClass('clicked');
        var currentCalories = +totalNum.html();
        var currentCarbs = +totalCarbs.html();
        var currentFats = +totalFats.html();
        var currentProteins = +totalProteins.html();

        if (pressed) {
            $(this).removeClass('clicked');
            var calories = $(this).data('calories');
            var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
            var fat = $(this).data('fat'); +
            totalNum.html(currentCalories - calories); +
            totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs - carbs); +
            totalFats.html(currentFats - fat); +
            totalProteins.html(currentProteins - proteins);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
            var calories = $(this).data('calories');
            var carbs = $(this).data('carbs');
            var fat = $(this).data('fat');
            var proteins = $(this).data('fat'); +
            totalNum.html(currentCalories + calories); +
            totalCarbs.html(currentCarbs + carbs); +
            totalFats.html(currentFats + fat); +
            totalProteins.html(currentProteins + fat);
        }

        // vegan      

        var vegan = false;
        $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function () {
            if (typeof $(this).attr("vegan") != "undefined") {
                vegan = true;
            } else {
                vegan = false;
                return false;
            }
        });



        if (vegan) {
            $('#type').text("Ez az összeállítás Vegán");
            $('#typeImage').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
        } else {
            $('#type').text("");

            $('#typeImage').attr("src", "");
        }

    });


    // vegetarian

    var vegetarian = false;
    $(".ingredient.clicked").each(function () {
        if (typeof $(this).attr("vegetarian") != "undefined") {
            vegetarian = true;
        } else {
            vegetarian = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    if (vegetarian) {
        $('#typeVega').text("Ez az összeállítás vegetáriánus");
        $('#typeImageVega').attr("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/hi/thumb/b/b2/Veg_symbol.svg/768px-Veg_symbol.svg.png");
    } else {
        $('#typeVega').text("");

        $('#typeImageVega').attr("src", "");
    }



});
```

```css
div,
p,
h1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
}

body {
    font-size: 1.0rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #42413f;
}

.header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.header img {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.header h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.ingredients {
    background: #f3f3f3 url(http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/whiteback.jpg) center top repeat;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 4px solid #6FC0BB;
    padding: 30px 60px;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ingredients h2 {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.ingredient {
    border: 2px solid #6FC0BB;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ingredient:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #6FC0BB;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #6FC0BB;
}

.ingredient:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.clicked {
    background-color: #6FC0BB;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #282828;
}

.total {
    margin-top: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    text-transform: ;
}

//* fonts *//
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lithos Pro Black';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Li Pro Black'), url('http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/LithosPro-Black.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lithos Pro Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Lithos Pro Regular'), url('http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/LithosPro-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
}


/*@font-face {
    font-family: 'Arial Narrow';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: local('Arial Narrow'), url('http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/8098062665.ttf') format('truetype');*/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two Italic';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: local('Lobster Two Italic'), url('http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/LobsterTwo-Italic.otf') format('opentype');
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/Proxima Nova Alt Condensed Light.otf');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url ('http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/content/fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Thin.otf');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Thin Italic.otf');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
    src: url('http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/fonts/Mark Simonson - Proxima Nova Thin.otf');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: italic;
}


/*  Fontok  */

p {
    font-family: "Arial Narrow";
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal !important;
}

.h-landmark span {
    font-family: 'Lithos Pro Black' !important;
}

h2 a,
h3,
h2 {
    font-family: 'Lithos Pro' !important;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 1.5em !important;
}

.x-brand {
    display: none;
}

.total {
    font-family: 'Lobster Two' !important;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1.3em !important;
}

.typeImage,
typeImagevega {
    height: 50px;
    width;
    50px;
}

.header img {
    height: 50px;
    width;
    50px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
        <img src="http://blog.padthaiwokbar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/logofinal.png" alt="padthai wokbar" style="width:300px;">
        <h1>How did you build your bowl?</h1>
        <p>Select all the ingredients you added to your padthai wokbar meal and we'll do the rest.</p>
        <br>


        <div class="ingredients">


            <h2 style="color:#6FC0BB;">Bases</h2>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian vegan>
                <p>Rice Noodles
                    <p>

            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian vegan>
                <p>Egg Noodles
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
                <p>Vermicelli
                    <p>

            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
                <p>Whole Grain Noodle
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegetarian>
                <p>White Rice
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Brown Rice
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Vegetable Base
                    <p>
            </div>


            <h2 style="color:#C84327;">Proteins</h2>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Chicken
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Pork
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Smoked Tofu
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Beef
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Duck
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Prawns
                    <p>
            </div>

            <h2 style="color:#90A94D;">Toppings</h2>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Vegetable Mix
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Cashew
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Sweet Peppers Mix
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Wood Ear Mushroom
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Mushroom
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Pineapple
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Bamboo Shots
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Chinese Cabbage
                    <p>
            </div>



            <h2 style="color:#424040;">Sauces</h2>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Thailand-Padthai
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Chinese Sweet and Sour
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Burma- Green Curry
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Indonesia- Satay
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Laosz- Red Curry
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Japan- Teriyaki
                    <p>
            </div>

            <h2 style="color:#6FC0BB;">Extra Toppings</h2>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Roasted Peanut
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Coriander
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Sesame Seed
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150">
                <p>Basil
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="300" data-carbs="150" data-fat="250" data-proteins="150" vegan>
                <p>Coconut Chips
                    <p>
            </div>

            <h2 style="color:#C84327;">Desserts</h2>

            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="40" data-carbs="250">
                <p>Cumin Lemon Vinaigrette
                    <p>
            </div>
            <div class="ingredient" data-calories="40" data-carbs="250">
                <p>Honey Cilantro Vinaigrette
                    <p>
            </div>

            <div class="total">
                Total calories: <span id="total"></span> Total Carbs:<span id="totalCarbs"></span> Total Fat:<span id="totalFats"></span> Total Protein:<span id="totalProteins"></span>

                <br>
                <img id="typeImage" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="Select Something!" />
                <span id="type"></span>
                <br>
                <img id="typeImageVega" src="" height="50px" width="50px" alt="Test" />
                <span id="typeVega"></span>
                <br>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't know how to make this more minimal. Basically there are two attributes that matter right now: 'vegan' and 'vegetarian'. Vegan does its job for items containing the 'vegan' attribute, but 'vegetarian' does not.

Comment: You don't really need all the `css` and every food item from your website to reproduce the issue. You would have got the answer within minutes of posting had you posted only the relevant code. Nobody has the time to go through 1000 lines of code and find the issue :)

Comment: My apologies, I'm a newbie here, will do so next time.

Comment: I have added the answer, please test it and let me know.

Comment: Don't apologize. I mean, in your case, you might feel, some `css` is important because of how the items look after they are clicked. Then you can create a [fiddle like this](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/c2v73p6q/) and post only relevant code here. But `font-face` and same `<div class="ingredient">` repeated multiple times are unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `vegetarian` related code is outside your `$('.ingredient').click()` handler.

```
$('.ingredient').click(function () {
    // variables
    // vegan code
});

// vegetarian code
```

Move it inside the click handler, below the vegan block.